# Updating Spinner loses its style

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-studio-3.0

Okay so I have a spinner in my layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/chapters"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/noborder"
    android:entries="@array/chapter_one"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:theme="@style/large_spinner"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="320dp" />
```

And I update it like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newChapters);
Chapters.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

While this works, (the spinners content gets updated) it loses its style - I'm guessing because I'm passing `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` which is changing the spinner into a simple one.

How can I retain the style when I update it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem was that I was passing the `simple_spinner_item` from `android.R.layout`.

So I created a new layout resource file (Right click `layout` and select `New layout resource file`) and copied the existing customer spinner XML into there, but with my background and theme added (named **large_spinner_item.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/assets/res/any/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml
**
** Copyright 2006, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:background="@drawable/noborder"
    android:theme="@style/large_spinner"/>
```

As you can see I left the comments in there from the original spinner so it I know where it came from.  Then, to use that resource I found this page that helped me try using the following:

`ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.large_spinner_item, newChapters);`

The key was to just use `R.layout` not `android.R.layout`.  Then my spinner retained all its style!